# Update values when null

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that is sending the values to the controller in this way:

```
public function postFormUpdate(ProjectUpdateRequest $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $project = $this->projectRepository->update($inputs['project_id'],$inputs);
    //...
}
```

The project repository is done this way:

```
public function update($id, Array $inputs)
    {
        return $this->save($this->getById($id), $inputs);
    }

    private function save(Project $project, Array $inputs)
    { 
    // Nullable
    if (isset($inputs['project_type'])) {$project->project_type = $inputs['project_type'];}
    if (isset($inputs['activity_type'])) {$project->activity_type = $inputs['activity_type'];}
...
}
```

My problem is if the project_type is null from the form field (the project type doesn't need to be entered or can be removed), then isset($inputs['project_type']) will be false and the update will not be triggered.

What I want is if the user had set up a project type and then wants to change it and set it to null, like this, it is not working. I use the isset because sometimes I update only one field and I don't want this to generate an error because it was not part of the inputs and was not set.

What I can do is use:

```
if (isset($inputs['project_type']) || is_null($inputs['project_type'])) {$project->project_type = $inputs['project_type'];}
```

But I am looking if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your new condition is always `true` although it will throw a warning if the variable does not exist. You probably want something like: `$project->project_type = $inputs['project_type'] ?? null;`; use it if it is not `null` and set it to `null` if it does not exist or is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant way would be to see if anything is set under the key.
so go with [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if ( array_key_exists('project_type', $inputs) ){$project->project_type = $inputs['project_type'];}
```

You may [see it in action here](https://3v4l.org/lQt37)